# How to automate flutter based app using appium? is there any separate driver or automation tool for flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, testing, automation, appium

I m not able find  proper id,xpath or other locator for flutter based app using Appium Inspector!
is there any separate driver in appium or separate automation tool for flutter based app?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPOw6.png)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you check out [Patrol](https://patrol.leancode.co). We created Patrol because Appium didn't work for us.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Patrol at LeanCode :)

[appium-flutter-driver](https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver) is poorly maintained, has lots of issues, and depends on `flutter_driver`, which is kinda deprecated and not developed anymore. The new way to do integration testing in Flutter is to use `integration_test` package, which is incompatible with Appium by design.
Furthermore, you write tests with Appium in Java/JavaScript (these are the most popular, I think). Patrol is Flutter-native and you can write tests in plain Dart (Patrol itself is also mostly written in Dart!).

Here are a few examples of what Patrol can do:

**Tap on native views (e.g WebViews)**

```dart
await $.native.enterText(
  Selector(text: 'Enter your email'),
  text: 'charlie@root.me',
);
await $.native.tap(Selector(text: 'Sign me up!'));
```

**Tap on notifications**

```dart
await $.native.openNotifications();

// tap on the first notification
await $.native.tapOnNotificationByIndex(0); 

// tap on notification by the text it contains
await $.native.tapOnNotificationBySelector(
  Selector(textContains: 'New message from user @charlie!'),
);
```

**Handle permission dialogs**

```dart
await $.native.grantPermissionWhenInUse();
await $.native.grantPermissionOnlyThisTime();
await $.native.denyPermission();
```

Learn more in [our docs](https://patrol.leancode.co) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***Flutter Inspector*** of Flutter . No need to use Appium .
Just Click on FlutterInspector on right side of Android Studio .Open it .You will see 2 options:-

```
 1)Layout Explorer
 2)Widget Details Tree
```

You can use this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Appium's traditional UiAutomator2 or XCUITest driver to find the UI elements of a Flutter-based app, then you may have issues finding the element using its attributes. This is because the element attributes are not visible to Appium. You may have to use XPath instead, which can be highly unreliable and slow.

To address this issue, Appium folks are working on a separate driver that can be used for automating Flutter-based applications. Apart from this, you can use Flutter's own Flutter driver. There could be other no-code tools as well that you can explore. Each of these options has pros and cons.

Let me list all the major options currently available. Go through it and evaluate it based on your requirements and skills.

**Appium's UiAutomator2/XCUITest Driver**

With these drivers, you may observe issues finding the UI elements using their attributes. Long XPath is frequently required. This is because all the element attributes used for UI elements in the Flutter app may not be visible to Appium UiAutomator2 or the XCUITest driver.

**Appium's Flutter Driver**

Appium has a Flutter driver that may solve the above issue, but it is still in the experimental phase. Here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/truongsinh/appium-flutter-driver

With this driver, you may be able to use Flutter's element attributes to find the elements. Since this is still in the experimental phase, you may observe other issues or some other limitations. Please do a small POC and see if this works for you.

Here's the Flutter element attributes list: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_driver/CommonFinders-class.html

**Flutter's Flutter Driver**

Flutter also has its own driver for automating Flutter apps, but it only supports the Dart language, which can be alien to many testers who are accustomed to Java. It may have limited support to the end to end tests that we usually write with Appium. Here's the link to the driver: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction

**Maestro (no-code tool)**

There is one emerging no-code tool called Maestro that supports Flutter apps. Currently, it supports only emulators and simulators. I have heard good things about this tool. You might want to check it out too. Here's the link: https://maestro.mobile.dev